# Simple fixed header with jQuery in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web-applications, reactjs

I have a problem like this:
in my page I have a header.
I'd love to have that header fixed when the screen in smaller,
and I'd like to have it fixed on my main page and one other page no-matter-what screen size is.

I'm trying to achieve it with jQuery. Actually it works, or it would work if I wasn't using react.
It works every time the page is reloded/resized. Before that, the values for 'height' are dragged from (I think so) previous page. To be precize: every time the page is reloaded but not when we're moving from A to B but when something happens inside A (A to A).

The code goes like this:

```
            render: function () { 
        $(function () {
        if (mediaQuery.isSmall() || $('.aWindow').length > 0 || $('.aDashboard').length > 0) {
            var headerHeight = $('.header').height();
            $('.header').addClass('fixed-header');
            $('.nextContainerInTheFlow').css('top', headerHeight);
        } else {
            $('.nextContainerInTheFlow').css('top', 0);
            $('.header').removeClass('fixed-header');
        }
    });

          <header className={isDashboardSelected ? 'header fixed-header' : 'header'}>
      /*other components inside header that doesnt rather matter*/
          </header>
          <main className={mainClass} role='main'>
              <bigComponent/> /*inside that bastard those aDashboard and aWindow are generated, depending what page user wants to display*/
             </main>
         }
```

The problem are those resizes/reloads needed to play that jQuery properly. I have actually no idea how to do it right, but I feel I need to put the code not in render but... somewhere else.
Or it's maybe something with those coponents being inside of bigComponent.

I need your help, and I'll be thaaaaaaat grateful :)

P.S.
I'd love to share the original code with you, but I can't.

Comment: You could have done this in pure css around the `position: fixed` attribute and media queries, your pages could set a class on the body and css would do the rest, nothing to do with react or jquery

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about it, but I would have to put a lot of media queries, as  the header height is changing with screen sizes and with different pages as well.
I'm taking it as a lesson, because if I fail, I'll use good old pure CSS to do that. 
Actually I got to this point, because I was simplifying more complex sticky header- which had to face the same bugs the smplified version has to face as well.